# update element of list of Complex object with linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Hi everybody and thanks in advance for solution

I've these objects

```
    List<AccessModuleInfo> listOfAccessModuleInfo = new List<AccessModuleInfo>();

    public class AccessModuleInfo
    {
       public int AccessModuleId { get; set; }
       public string AccessModuleName { get; set; }
       public List<AccessRoleInfo> ListOfAccessRole { get; set; }

     }

    public class AccessRoleInfo
    {
      public int AccessRoleId { get; set; }
      public string AccessRoleName { get; set; }
      public bool AccessRoleValue { get; set; }
    }
```

I receive listOfAccessModuleInfo that is already fill and when I try to update AccessRoleValue in specific AccessModuleInfo, all AccessRoleValue with the same AccessRoleId are updated .

I want update only AccessRoleValue of specific AccessModuleInfo (for example with AccessModuleId = 4)

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Does AccessRoleInfo point back to AccessModuleInfo at all? Also, why is AccessRoleValue a bool?

Comment: thanks for resposnse.now i'm out of office but i think that new version library attach the same ListOfAccessRole pointer; so i think when update the right element , framework update all its pointer reference .Tomorrow talk with programmer but I'm quite sure prb is that.Thanks again :)

Comment: It would have been helpful if you posted the LINQ statement for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally something like this should work just fine:

```
// You didn't confuse == vs = did you?
// Single also helps us debug and ensure we're only getting one result
var itemToUpdate = listOfAccessModuleInfo.Where(x => x.AccessModuleId == 4).Single();
itemToUpdate.ListOfAccessRole.ForEach(x => x.AccessRoleValue = newValue);
```